# Should functions be responsibile for checking if required params exists at runtime?

Tags: typescript

With TypeScript you have no runtime guarantees, so I was wondering where to actually check whether or not a function param exists.

Trusting TypeScript, assuming someRequiredParam will never be undefined or null:

```
function myFunc(someRequiredParam: { foo: string, bar: string }) {
  return JSON.stringify(someRequiredParam);
}
```

This will work fine at compile time, but could blow up at runtime.

NOT trusting TypeScript, but then why ever use required params?

```
function myFunc(someRequiredParam: { foo: string, bar: string }) {
  if (isText(someRequiredParam?.foo) && isText(someRequiredParam?.bar)) {
    return JSON.stringify(someRequiredParam);
  }
}
```

Seems redundant to have these runtime checks when you already have typed them as required.

In the above case I might as well define the param and its nested props as optional

```
function myFunc(someRequiredParam?: { foo?: string, bar?: string }) {
  if (isText(someRequiredParam?.foo) && isText(someRequiredParam?.bar)) {
    return JSON.stringify(someRequiredParam);
  }
}
```

But then you lose the strong typing at dev/compile time, which doesn't seem right.

Of course you could also check if the values exist before passing them on to the function, however relying on that doesn't seem right either.

I think it's a lot easier to work with a sound type system you can trust, like e.g. the one in ReScript, where you won't have these runtime errors after your code compiles, because the language forces you to handle cases equivalent to null/undefined in TS/JS.

But I'm very curious to know, how people utilize TypeScript so it's not giving you a false sense of security by only catching errors at compile time. Is using a lot of type guards what people typically do? And do you use them inside functions to check if required params exist at runtime?

Comment: Replace TypeScript with C in your question. Is it the same? The security in TypeScript is that whatever you are using is also strongly typed (if it doesn't have types, give it types). Sure, if you are writing a library, you might add those checks in because of pesky JavaScript users, but if you are writing an application, you probably don't, since (hopefully) you trust yourself.

Comment: C is also a strongly typed (low-level) language. My analogy was that if you are concerned about TypeScript (a strongly typed language), should the same concerns be applied to other strongly typed languages? Probably not. You know Java or C will only give you what you expect. So is TypeScript. Unless you are writing a library which can be used by JavaScript users, then it is safe to add checks to prevent unwanted input.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem you are envisioning?  Who is calling your TypeScript function?  Is it some third party JavaScript code that doesn't know about TypeScript? Then yeah, you have a problem.  Is it other TypeScript code inside your code base or in a project that imports your typings?  Then you probably don't have a problem (unless you're talking about TS's [soundness issues](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) which isn't perfect but I'd like to know what you're thinking of).

Comment: If the TS-emitted-JS is *intended* to be run by JS that doesn't know about it *and* you expect that JS to call your function without knowing what it expects, then you should give your functions insanely loose typings like `function myFunc(...args: unknown[]) {}` and do whatever testing you feel necessary in the function.  But otherwise, any runtime problem by noncompliant JS is really the fault of the that JS caller.  If you buy a pet dog from me and feed it rocks, is that *my* fault? I'd really love to know what situation you're envisioning here.

Comment: I think your comments makes good sense. However, I guess what I was looking for was more like what the best practices would be in TS? How defensive to code. It seems odd to me that if you type function params to type DogFood, orders a bag of dog food but receives a bag of rocks, yet the dog eats it anyways without barking. This is what confuses me about TypeScript - that no runtime checking happens. So got curious how defentive (or not) people would write their code, to figure out if I should make more use of type guards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are within the boundaries of your own module and it is safely-typed in TypeScript then you can trust your type signatures.

If you are interacting with another system, or a server, then definitely add checks when data from outside sources moves into your modules.

TypeScript is mostly sound. In my experience, in production type errors are fairly rare if you pay attention to boundaries.

Comment: So if interacting with "another system, or a server" (io right?) then you generally don't use  required function params and required nested props on those params? Everything will be defined as optional to not give that false sense of security?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by required functions params and nested props. As far as I see it, those are just the same thing as the type parameters of the function. *All* type systems are built on the assumption that if you say a variable is some type then its value will be of that type. If you say something is an int then it won't be a string hiding in disguise. Type systems assert that if you follow the rules then all steps after that remained well typed. Once you are in a well typed space you don't leave it.

Comment: Of course, when interacting with the real world you never know what you will get. This is why when you do IO, either from files on disk, or over the network, that is when you do runtime checks. Once you have well-typed data then you can trust your type system and your program state will be valid.